# How do I delete a branch I created and revert everything back to the master branch's last commit?

Tags: git

The last commit I made to the master branch is where I want to get everything back to. I made a lot of changes and committed them to a new branch I created called omniauth. I would like to delete this branch entirely and restore everything back to the last master commit. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can switch back to the `master` branch with:

```
git checkout master
```

Then you can delete the `omniauth` branch with:

```
git branch -D omniauth
```

Note that the `-D` option (as opposed to the safer `-d`) will delete the branch regardless of whether the commits in that branch have been merged into your current branch.